# chrome setTimeout and fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to do a delayed fade out of a div.  I am using JQuery but none of the delay methods work in Chrome 16, all is fine in FF 10.

```
msgCenter.style.display = "inline";
setTimeout('$("#messageCenter").hide("fade", { }, 1000);',4000);
$('#messageCenter').delay(4000).fadeOut();
```

Neither of these work in Chrome.

This will work in Chrome but has no fade effect:

```
setTimeout('$("#messageCenter").hide();',4000);
```

Can anyone tell me why?  Also is there a way I can add a fading effect to Chrome?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Use an anonymous function as suggested by @Zenexer below. Also why do you set a style like this and not just use `.css()` for it? Just curious.

Comment: I am old school, way before JQuery existed, so I tend to use the language rather than the framework.

Comment: Does the console on Chrome give any error?

Comment: no Chrome reports no error on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I set it to

```
msgCenter.style.display = "block";
```

it works for all the options mentioned above! Seems strange to me. Anyone know why it must be block and not inline?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#messageCenter").css('display', 'block').fadeOut();
}, 4000);
```

And if fadeIn is encountering issues, too:

```
$("#messageCenter").css({display: 'block', opacity: 0}).fadeIn();
```

Comment: this does not work for me, it does if I set the display to block.

Comment: What type of element is #messageCenter?

Comment: Then it should be display: block to begin with.

Comment: to begin with it is display:none as it is a hidden element until invoked

Comment: Ah.  jQuery is supposed to automatically change that to block, but apparently it's not doing so.  I'll update my answer with another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a JQuery animation, like one of the following:

```
setTimeout('$("#messageCenter").fadeOut();', 4000);
setTimeout('$("#messageCenter").animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 1000, function() { /* Animation complete */});', 4000);
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the response.  This also does not function for me unless I set the display to block.  msgCenter.style.display = "block";

Answer (score 1):

Your second option should work. I set up a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/y86zn/) which works on Chrome 16.0.912.77.

Comment: Just changed `display` to `inline` and it still seems OK. [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/zHgKN/).

Comment: hello.  Thanks for the effort. I forked the fiddle (running very slow that fiddle got 504s more than once) and updated it with the div that I have etc.  http://jsfiddle.net/b6zMm/1/  It does not work in chrome, as your fiddles do.  I think it might be somehthing to do with the deadly inline styles that are being used.  You will see if you change to this line div.style.display = "block"; it will work in chrome

Comment: I set `display:none` and added your javascript, and it _still_ works in Chrome(17). [Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AyWPE/). Maybe the problem lies elsewhere in your HTML.

Comment: hello it is my div definition.  If you try this fiddle in Chrome it will not work.  If you cnage the div.style.display to block then it will work in chrome, thanks for the input and setting up the original fiddle +1

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#messageCenter').css("display","block").fadeOut(4000,function() {
        $(this).css("display","inline");    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also `try $("#messageCenter").hide(4000)`...this will give a shrink animation...but for your case use `$("#messageCenter").fadeIn(4000)` or `$("#messageCenter").fadeOut(4000)`